# Django displays hidden form field for random callable deafult values in ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a default value as callable for one of the model fields. I am using ModelForm to output it. From the docs what i understand is, the callable is called only when a new object is created.

What i don't understand is why am i getting a hidden field for the field specified with a default callable..
I am getting the following output,

```
>>> form = SomeForm()
>>> print form['eventID']

<input id="id_eventID" maxlength="255" name="eventID" type="text" value="event_2c6b2259" /><input id="initial-id_eventID" name="initial-eventID" type="hidden" value="event_cee183d7" />
```

and everytime i print the above statement, it gives me a different value for eventID, (I have the default value as a random callable..)
But from what i understand is, the callable should be called only once when the instance of the form has been created.
Isn't it right ?

**UPDATE:** 
forms.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EiEventType
```

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    eventID = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,default=random_eventID)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=two_min_from_now)
    signal = models.ManyToManyField(Signal,null=True)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

The random function is as defined below,

```
def random_eventID()
    return "event_" + str(uuid.uuid4())[:5]

def two_min_from_now()
    return datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=2)
```

Comment: Can you post the code to your ModelForm?

Comment: @TimEdgar i have updated the question with all the relevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: add parentheses to invoke the function instead of passing a function.  `default=random_eventID()`

Long Answer:

It looks that `ModelForm` saves the function as the default value and uses it as if it were a value. It's calling the function over and over again as you've observed.  When you create a model instance `Event()` it'll work by calling your function once on init and won't change each time you access it.

However, when you create an `EventForm` I suspect it's storing as the default value the function reference since it isn't actually creating a model instance, but simply populating it from the various properties of the model through an import.

You can notice this behavior by putting a debugging breakpoint in your function and see it being called multiple times when it's `random_eventID` with different stack traces and being called once when it's `random_eventID()` during the import of the model class.

```
def random_eventID()
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return "event_" + str(uuid.uuid4())[:5]
```

Comment: That was really helpful Tim! Superb understanding..Thank You so much..But any specific reason that it also creates a hidden field in my form, just curious to know ??

Comment: It looks like the hidden field is an artifact of having different values for eventID.  When you use random_eventID(), it seems to go away in my testcase.

Comment: Yes , it does go away in my case as well. Anyways thanks for the brilliant understanding!!

Comment: can you look at another question posted by me, i feel to misinterpret somethings. Thanks!